# How to write negative one as an unsigned literal in C++

Tags: c++, literals, unsigned

In my program, I often use -1 (aka UINT_MAX) as a value for unsigned variables to denote something special.  I also compare against this value.  Turning on higher levels of warning messages reveals that compilers (both VS and GCC) do not like this syntax.

```
// warning C4245: 'initializing' : conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
unsigned a = -1;

// warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
unsigned b = -1U;

// fine but messy
unsigned c = unsigned(-1);

// no warning on VS, signed/unsigned comparison warning with GCC
if (a == -1)
{
  std::cout << "check\n";
}
```

Question 1: Is the syntax given above (each case) legitimate C++ code?

Question 2: Do I really have to write unsigned(-1) everywhere I use this value to assign/compare to an unsigned int or is there a cleaner way that will not trigger a compiler warning?

Comment: What do you have against using `UINT_MAX`?

Comment: [`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer 1:

Yes, they are both proper, albeit arguably unpleasant, C++ constructs.

- `-1` is interpreted as an int literal.  It is proper C++ syntax, as the standard allows for implicit int to unsigned int conversion, but the compiler warns when this implicit conversion is used at higher warning levels.
- `-1U` is intepreted as `-(1U)`.  Taking the negative of an unsigned int is proper C++ syntax, as the compiler performs this operation modulo `(UINT_MAX + 1)`, however the compiler issues a warning letting you know.
- `(unsigned(-1) == -1)` is also proper syntax, as the compiler implicitly converts `-1` to `unsigned(-1)` for the comparison.  It does warn you about the implicit conversion at higher warning levels to let you know it has done so.

Answer 2:

There are several options to write or effect `unsigned(-1)` as a literal:

- Write `unsigned(-1)`.
- Write `~0U`, which, on a two's compement machine, takes `0` and then negates each bit, which gives the largest representable unsigned number.
- Write `UINT_MAX` which is effectively `#define`d as `unsigned(-1)`.
- If assigned or comparing to an unsigned value, write `-1` and let the compiler do the implicit conversion and cope with the warning messages.  However, it should be noted that -1 is an int literal and only gets converted to unsigned based on its function in the code.
- Write `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` which is a function which returns `unsigned(-1)`.  Note that in In C++11 this function will be a constexpr which a good compiler should always simplify into a literal.  VC++ currently simplifies this away into `unsigned(-1)` for non-debug builds.  It is, however, a value returned from a function call and not a literal.

Comment: How is the next guy to maintain this code to know whether you meant "-1" or "the biggest unsigned number"? -1 is **signed** and should be treated as such!

Comment: Pretend I called it UINT_MAX in the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 6):

**By its very nature, you cannot write negative one as an unsigned literal in C++ or any other language.**

You don't mean `-1`, you mean [**`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    unsigned a = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

    if (a == std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max())
    {
        std::cout << "check " << a << "\n";
    }
}
```

The C++11 standard made this function [**`constexpr`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), which guarantees that the function is a compile-time constant. ([Further reading](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/sac10-constexpr.pdf)).

If you want to avoid calculating this for every iteration of a loop using an older compiler, create a `const` outside the loop and compare this:

```
const unsigned int magic_number = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

    // [...]
    if (a == magic_number)
```

Comment: Well, -1 is a compile time constant whereas std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() is not, as far as I can tell.  Since I'm using this in a comparison on large loops, I'd like the added efficiency.

Comment: I appreciate the notes, but calling a constexpr function still isn't a literal.  I did clarify what I meant by -1 as UINT_MAX in the first sentence.  The title was so search engines would properly tag it.  A search revealed nothing useful as "-1" is hard for search engines to handle.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to deal with the length of an int, you can use

```
~0
```

This gives you all ones, which on a twos-complement machine (are there any others still these days?) is the same as -1.  But it is a legit unsigned long.

Comment: You might want to put an assertion somewhere that the machine is two's complement. The alternatives aren't common, but it doesn't really take any effort and portability is good even just as an exercise.

Comment: My VS compiler says ~0 is an int and so the warnings are identical.

Comment: What do you mean by `it is a legit unsigned long`?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the discussion thread at the end of this article.

http://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2011/06/is-uint16_t-1-portable-c-code/

The upshot is that (unsigned)(-1) is perfectly legal and is guaranteed to have the maximum value for that type, regardless of actual width or internal representation.

Whether or not it's a good idea is another question. Personally, I prefer the solution offered by Johnsyweb.

As to whether or not you always need the cast, that's going to be compiler dependent. Since you've tried VS and GCC, it seems so.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using ULONG_MAX?
You need to include limits.h.

Alternatively, you can also use 0xFFFFFFFF -- properly defined in a macro or static constant, of course.

Comment: Since this is c++, better to use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()`.

Comment: UINT_MAX is a define (ULONG_MAX isn't relevant) and 0xFFFFFFFFL is a long, not an unsigned, and is system specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not mess unsigned and signed. -1 is Signed and should stay in that way, maybe it is a design problem that you want to have -1 often. There are solutions like boost::optional.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

example:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::optional<int> find (const std::string& s, char t)
{
   for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length () ; ++ i)
   if (s [i] == t)
   return i ;
   return boost::optional<int>() ;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    std::string s = argv[1] ;
    char t = *argv[2] ;
    boost::optional<int> idx = find (s, t) ;
    if (idx)
        std::cout << "found at " << *idx << std::endl ;
    else
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Including Boost for the purposes of writing -1 as an unsigned literal is not an option.  There are plenty of uses for -1 on unsigned variables, for example see the many uses in std::string.

Comment: @devtk for std::string you should be writing `std::string::npos`. But there are legitimate uses. For example, wcswidth() returns a size_t but reports errors by returning -1. So comparing the return value against `(size_t)-1` or `size_t(-1)` is the right way to do it.